# Two different menus for two different locations?

Tags: functions, menus

I'm trying to change the menu in a primary and a secondary menu depending on the page which is visited.

My primary menu is in the top of the page, and it looks like this:

---

Index | About | Contact

---

And my second menu is a dropdown menu, under the header, and it looks like this:

---

Write New | Help | Profile |

---

So, the thing is that whenever you visit profile for example, I want to change both menus for others I've already created.

So reading I found something but it doesn't work at all:  in the file functions.php I added:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );

function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args) {
if( is_page('2') ) {
        $args['menu'] = 'Original Menu';
} else {
        $args['menu'] = 'Menu for Profile';
}
    return $args;
}
```

It works, but it changes primary and secondary menus with the 'Menu for Profile', and I want it only for the primary. I've tried adding ['theme_location'] = 'primary' but what it does is dissapear both menus.

I hope you can help me, and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably used the theme location part wrongly. Here is an example of how it should be done

Follow the comments in code for explanation :-)

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', function ( $args ) 
{
    if (    is_page( 2 ) //Only target page 2 
         && $args['theme_location'] === 'primary' ) { // Check and only target the primary menu
    ) {
        $args['menu'] = 'Menu for Profile';
    }
    return $args;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to create two menus and call them with a conditional in `header.php` file, like this:

```
if ( is_page( 'about' ) ) { 
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'           => 'primary', 
        'theme_location' => 'primary'
    ) ); 
} else { 
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'           => 'second_menu', 
        'theme_location' => 'primary'
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Please reread the question.