# Change menu based on page template via functions.php

Tags: functions, menus

I'm trying to swap out the main menu of a page if it uses a specific page template.

This was working perfectly until I added a 2nd menu to the page.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to target only the primary-menu and not all the menus on the page. I tried 'primary-menu' but did not work.

In functions.php:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', function ($args) {
  if (is_page_template('page-template-custom.php')) {
    $args['menu'] = 'custom-menu';
  }
  return $args;
});
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two different menus for two different locations?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208893/two-different-menus-for-two-different-locations)

Comment: Thanks is brilliant! Thank you Michael! I had to make a small modification though as the brackets may be misplaced and swapped "is_page" with "is_page_template" and voila!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$args` the filter is receiving includes the `theme_location` used when the menu was registered, so assuming your main location is `primary`, you can add the following to your if statement to target only that menu:

```
    if ( 
      is_page_template( 'page-template-custom.php' ) && 
      isset( $args['theme_location'] ) &&
      'primary' === $args['theme_location'] )
    ) { ...
```

See:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_args/
and
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menu/
for reference

Comment: This is perfect and works great! While this is similar to the link provided by Micheal, this solves my issue exactly for page templates - much gratitude thank you!